# Window buttons do not belong to the top window?

Tags: 12.04, unity, window-buttons

Sometimes in Ubuntu 12.04 (no modifications), when application X is on top of the screen (i.e. it is the window that I see), the close and minimise buttons are *not* from application X.

Thus, when I click 'close' suddenly another application gets closed and not the one that appeared on top. Why is this so? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this Unity bugreport, it's an annoying one but still not fixed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/781931

Comment: Everyone: let's sign-in into Launchpad and vote as `This affects me` so that may be this bug attracts more attention. It is really disturbing and causes bad mistakes often yet still not even assigned for more than 1 year!

Comment: @destan I wish I could but I get a timeout error everytime I click on "yes it affects me too". Reported as launchpad bug long ago ;-)